# JavaScriptCore broken with iOS 10

Tags: javascript, ios, ios10, javascriptcore

I'm seeing some very strange behavior with JavaScriptCore on iOS 10. I'm using it to execute some JS script that performs some logic in my application. On iOS 9, everything works fine. However, on iOS 10, the script will run maybe one or twice and then will stop executing with message such as

> Error compiling builtin: Invalid private name '@undefined'

I'm using a single JSVirtualMachine that loads and compiles the JavaScript code once. Then, each time there is a computation to be done by a component, I create a new JSContext which will perform the computation. After debugging a few hours, I noticed that if I don't use a single JSVirtualMachine but rather create a new instance for each component that needs to execute the JS script, it works.

That's very surprising and something I never say on iOS 8 or 9. Is anyone aware of a change on iOS 10 in that regards?

Thanks!

Comment: Please report bugs (especially in Beta software) to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Can you provide specific code examples demonstrating the error?

Comment: I am working on trying to provide some code to demonstrate if but it might take a while because the behavior changes if the JSCode is smaller for example - which kills the intent of providing a small reproducer. But stay tuned.